# How to write string to file in different lines in C

Tags: c, string, file, replace, cpu-word

I have program that replaces a word in a file with another one, but in the new file the lines are all written as one line, not in different lines and paragraphs as required.

I tried adding `'\n'` at the end of each line I am reading from the original file, but it is not working.

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    char word[MAX], fname[MAX];
    char s[MAX], replace[MAX];
    char temp[] = "temp.txt", *p1, *p2;
    printf("Enter your input file name:");
    fgets(fname, MAX, stdin);
    fname[strlen(fname) - 1] = '\0';

    scanf("%s", word);

    scanf("%s", replace);

    f1 = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (!f1) {
        printf("Unable to open the input file!!\n");
        return 0;
    }
    f2 = fopen(temp, "w");
    if (!f2) {
        printf("Unable to open temporary file!!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    while (fscanf(f1,"%[^\n]%*c", &s) != EOF) {
        printf("%s",s); //I wanted to see what happens when I'm reading from the file. Previously I added at the end of string s the char '\n' but it didnt work

        if (strstr(s, word)) {
            p2 = s;
            while (p1 = strstr(p2, word)) {
                while (p2 != p1) {
                    fputc(*p2, f2);
                    p2++;
                }
                p1 = p1 + strlen(word);
                fprintf(f2, "%s", replace);
                p2 = p1;
            }
            while (*p2 != '\0') {
                fputc(*p2, f2);
                p2++;
            }
        } else {
            fputs(s, f2);
        }
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);

    remove(fname);

    rename(temp, fname);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you wrote some code with instructions to read anything other than a newline, and the problem with it is that it doesn't read newlines? I'm not sure ...

Answer (score 1):

The simple reason is that you are not outputting a newline to the file. The `fscanf` doesn't include the newline in `s` (because you specifically omit it with `[^\n]`, which means "characters *other than* newline").

If you just add `putc('\n', f2);` at the very end of the outer `while` loop, it works fine.

Alternatively, you could just read with `fgets`, which does include the newline in the string. An added benefit is that `fgets` forces you to specify the maximum length as an argument, while guarding against excessive line length with `fscanf` requires you to put the length in the format string itself.

(Note that the `printf("%s", s);` has no effect on what goes into the file, since it outputs to `stdout`.)

Comment: It works ! Thank you so much. I have a question , though. Why didnt it work when i tried adding the '\n' at the end of each string s which contained each line from the original file?

Comment: @MaryPoppins Hard to say without seeing how you tried to add it, but when added like: `int len = strlen(s); s[len] = '\n'; s[len + 1] = '\0';` right after reading, it should work. (However, no need to do this, just read with `fgets` and it will be included. Or, if you really want to read with `fscanf`, print the newline at the end – adding it to the string _properly_ requires obtaining the length and checking bounds.)

Comment: warning as I said in my answer if the read line through fgets is longer than MAX you will probably cut the line and the word between the two fgets will not be replaced

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fgets()` to read from the input file instead of `fscanf(f1,"%[^\n]%*c", &s)` for multiple reasons:

- you do not give `fscanf()` to maximum number of characters to store into `s`: any sufficiently long line in the input file will cause undefined behavior.
- you read the line from `f1` and explicitly skip the newline, this explains why the newline never gets written to `f2`.
- `fscanf()` will fail on an empty line because there are no characters different from `\n` to read into `s`, `s` is unmodified and gets handled like the previous line (or undefined behavior on the first line), and the loop iterates at the same spot in the input file, effectively stuck forever writing to `f2` to no avail...

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX  100

int main() {
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    char word[MAX], fname[MAX];
    char s[MAX], replace[MAX];
    char temp[] = "temp.txt";
    char *p1, *p2;

    printf("Enter your input file name: ");
    if (!fgets(fname, sizeof fname, stdin))
        return 1;
    fname[strcspn(fname, "\n")] = '\0';  /* strip the newline if present */

    printf("Enter the word to search: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", word) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter the replacement word: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", replace) != 1)
        return 1;

    f1 = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (!f1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open the input file %s\n", fname);
        return 1;
    }
    f2 = fopen(temp, "w");
    if (!f2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open temporary file %s\n", temp);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(s, sizeof s, f1)) {
        p1 = s;
        while ((p2 = strstr(p1, word)) != NULL) {
            while (p1 < p2) {
                fputc(*p1++, f2);
            }
            fputs(replace, f2);
            p1 += strlen(word);
        }
        fputs(p1, f2);
    }

    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);

    remove(fname);
    rename(temp, fname);
    return 0;
}
```

Note however that if the input file has very long lines with matches spanning multiple chunks read by `fgets()`, these matches will be missed by the program.

Here is a different approach to avoid this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX  100

int main() {
    FILE *f1, *f2;
    char fname[MAX], word[MAX], replace[MAX];
    char temp[] = "temp.txt";
    char *p1 *p2;
    int c;

    printf("Enter your input file name: ");
    if (!fgets(fname, sizeof fname, stdin))
        return 1;
    fname[strcspn(fname, "\n")] = '\0';  /* strip the newline if present */

    printf("Enter the word to search: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", word) != 1)
        return 1;

    printf("Enter the replacement word: ");
    if (scanf("%99s", replace) != 1)
        return 1;

    f1 = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (!f1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open the input file %s\n", fname);
        return 1;
    }
    f2 = fopen(temp, "w");
    if (!f2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open temporary file %s\n", temp);
        return 1;
    }

    p2 = word;
    while ((c = getc(f1)) != EOF) {
        if (c != '\0' && *p2 == (char)c) {
            p2++;
            if (*p2 == '\0') {
                fputs(replace, f2);
                p2 = word;
            }
        } else {
            for (p1 = word; p1 < p2;) {
                putc(*p1++, f2);
                /* find potential match for special cases: find aab in aaab */
                if (!memcmp(word, p1, p2 - p1) && word[p2 - p1] == (char)c)
                    p2 = word + (p2 - p1) + 1;
                    p1 = word;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (p1 == p2) {
                putc(c, f2);
            }
        }
    }
    /* flush potential partial match at end of file */
    for (p1 = word; p1 < p2; p1++) {
        putc(*p1, f2);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);

    remove(fname);
    rename(temp, fname);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a first error is to give the address of *s* to fscanf, `fscanf(f1,"%[^\n]%*c",&s)` must be `fscanf(f1,"%[^\n]%*c",s)`

anyway, just replace your *fscanf* by a simple *fgets* and all will be ok, you will not loose \n

P.S. if you cannot be sure MAX is not enough to handle lines you have to manage the case a line is cut in several at read, and may be the word to replace in cut because of that. There are several ways to do that.

Comment: i tried replacing it with fscanf without the address, although i dont understand why, and its still not working. I tried the fgets version too, but its even worse because now , readin all the file in one string with fgets and replacing the words, the final file is not complete.

Comment: to remove the _&_ just allow to give a `char *` rather than a `char **` to _fscanf_ because this is the expected type.

Comment: @bruno `&s` is not the cause of the problem here, the address is still the same, so as long as `char *` and `char (*)[MAX]` have the same representation, it works with both. (But, yes, `s` without the `&` is correct.)

Comment: I say to use a fgets because you need to read line per line to replace the word by an other, you don't need to use a regexp for that

Comment: @Arkku sorry but for me your remark is catastrophic, even we are _only_ in c rather than c++ the expected types must be respected

Comment: @bruno Yes, and like I said, `s` is correct and `&s` is wrong. However, this is not the cause of the OP's problem (missing newline), since on their platform the `char *` (`s`) and `char (*)[MAX]` (`&s`) have the same representation and thus work the same in this context.

Comment: @MaryPoppins for me replacing fscanf by fgets seems to work well, why you sau is worst ? can you give an example ?

Comment: @MaryPoppins BTW, when testing, are you remembering to replace the input file with a fresh copy every time? If you run a broken version of the program, it overwrites the file with the version that doesn't have newlines.

Answer (score 0):

So you want modify words in a file, but keep all whitespace as is? Then it is important to read and write the whitespace. Using read-functions that skips whitespace won't help you much.

Here is a generic version of a read-modify loop. Fixing bugs and extending it to a compete program, including error handling, is left as exercise to the reader

```
while (1)
  {
    // Read the next character
    int ch = fgetc(infile);
    if (ch == EOF)
       break;  // read error or eof

    if (isspace(ch))
       {
          // The character was a whitespace, so we copy it to the outputstream
          int err = fputc(ch, outfile);
          if (err == EOF)
            break; // error
       }
    else
      {
        // The next character was not a whitespace, so we put it back in the
        //  inputstream for scanf to find it
        ungetc(ch, instream);

        char word[64]; // Just assume for simplicity that no words are longer 
                       // than 63 character.

        // Read the next string, making sure we don't read more than the buffer
        // can handle. A robust program should do something useful if words are
        // actually longer than 63 characters
        int len = fscanf(infile, "%63s", word);

        if (len == EOF)
           break;  // error (should not happen since there is guarantied to be
                     // one non-whitespace character in the stream)

        char mod_word[64];
        modify_word(mod_word, word);

        int err = fputs(mod_word, outfile);
        if (err == EOF)
           break; // error
     }
}

// Check for read-write errors
if (ferror(infile))
  perror("Failure reading from input file");
if (ferror(outfile))
  perror("Failure writing to output file");
```

Comment: Note that the length of the target word (to be replaced) is already known, so if the maximum word length is an issue, it would also suffice to just buffer up to the length of the target word and copy any overflow directly to output (since a longer word cannot match it).

Comment: @Arkku, yes, and it could also be possible to match single characters as they are read from the input stream without buffering whole words. But i just wanted it to be generic and simple. No need to teach a beginner to many tricks at once :-)